# Where is the safe place to download Firefox?

Tags: distribution

I would like to use an open source web browser, but I see lots of different places offering a download of Firefox. How do I tell which one is the correct place to download from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Firefox support question, not a question relevant to people who participate in open source projects. See [this meta thread](https://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/150/are-questions-about-specific-software-on-topic).

Comment: There is a possible question about why this is a huge issue for software licensed under floss licenses - adding unsafe stuff into them might actually be legal. But that would involved more research to be a good question anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wherever possible, you should download software directly from the vendor. If that's not possible, use a trusted, preferably secure (HTTPS) alternative source.

Firefox is made and released by Mozilla, so you should download from them wherever possible. The downloads page is [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/).

---

There are some indicators I use to determine how trustworthy a downloads site is:

- Page written in bad English - **bad** but not 'leave this site now'
- Page served over HTTP - ditto
- Page *doesn't have* a HTTPS version (not just they served over HTTP, but no secure version exists) - **bad**
- "FREE! ABSOLUTELY FREE! NO RISK! VIRUS SAFE!" - **get away from there**
- If they can't get the name right (["Fire Fox", anyone?](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEgQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.downloadfirefoxbrowser.com%2F&ei=Cm-VVdxTpqnsBpGGgKAD&usg=AFQjCNHzYR1m0BY7wnJDE-pFJq2WOv-qWg&sig2=9N5zYyB5v2OZyb7bTwXUkA&bvm=bv.96952980,d.ZGU)) - **bad**

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know if you are at the correct site is to look for a "clean" link. By this I mean:

- no subdomains (ie: `firefox.download.ca`)
- look for `https` in the url

In this example, this is the correct link for downloading mozilla firefox:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/